# Best way to access Office 2010 APIs

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ms-office, office-2010

We are currently investigating options for migrating a legacy application built using .NET 1.1 to .NET 4. Office 2003 was used in the application and we need to migrate away to Office 2010.

The old application used CDO/MAPI to interact with Excel/Outlook... so what is the prescribed p&p for accessing Excel/Outlook 2010 from .NET 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still COM, but there have been some upgrades to make it nicer. Things like:

- NoPIA
- Optional Parameters
- Optional ref Parameters
- Indexed Properties

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CLRAndDLRAndBCLOhMyWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I suppose VSTO (Visual Studio Tool for Office) is what you are looking for.